# Is there a reason this runs with 3 inputs but not 2?

Tags: java, input

When user gives input for name1, name2, and name3, the output is fine. However, when only name1 and name2 receive input, there is an error?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Type your code here. */
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String name1, name2, name3;

        name1 = scnr.next();
        name2 = scnr.next();
        name3 = scnr.next();

        if (name3.equals("")){
            System.out.println(name2 + ", " + name1.charAt(0) + ".");
        }
        else{
            name3 = name3.substring(0);
            System.out.println(name3 + ", " + name1.charAt(0) + "." + name2.charAt(0) + ".");
        }
   }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:12)
```

Comment: Hi, when you say "when only name1 and name2 receive input", how does that happen, have you changed your code or are you doing something else to make that happen, it's not really clear enough to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name3 = scnr.next();
```

is throwing the java.util.NoSuchElementException because there is no third input. You are trying read from System.in and there is nothing there to read.